# Python: correct way to pass objects between modules

Tags: python, module

I am following the [Flask SQLalchemy Quickstart](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html) which has all of the code in a single file:

Here is my initial **index.py**:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# [snip] - some classes related to SQLAlchemy are here 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I want to split the code up a bit, so I created a separate file called **database.py** which will contain all of the database related code, and be imported as a module.

I modified my **index.py** to look like this:

```
from flask import Flask

# Import my database module
import database

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

And the file **database.py**:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI]'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# [snip] - some classes related to SQLAlchemy are here
```

Obviously when I try to run this code I get the following error:

```
File "database.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI]'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

I can see that this is because the `app` object only exists within the parent module.

I could put the following lines back into **index.py**:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

But this creates a similar problem, whereby `db` is not available within the database.py file.

What is the correct way to code this?

Answer (score 1):

You can import the object `app` into `database.py` by putting:

```
from index import app
```

in `database.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Edited answer after comment:

Simply use

```
from index import app
```

in database.py.

Alternatively, with the

```
import index
```

statement, use `index.app` instead of `app` only.

This should help you get out of python's import hell.

Btw: Not sure which IDE you are using. I like pycharm a lot. Using it you can refactor code and issues such as above are prevented automagically.

Comment: I think you got the relationship the wrong way around: `index` defines `app`, `database` needs it.